# S3 file not downloaded when triggering a Lambda function associated with EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-efs

I'm using the Serverless framework to create a Lambda function that, when triggered by an S3 upload (uploading `test.vcf` to `s3://trigger-test/uploads/`), downloads that uploaded file from S3 to EFS (specifically to the `/mnt/efs/vcfs/` folder). I'm pretty new to EFS and followed AWS documentation for setting up the EFS access point, but when I deploy this application and upload a test file to trigger the Lambda function, it fails to download the file and gives this error in the CloudWatch logs:

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/efs/vcfs/test.vcf.A0bA45dC'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 21, in download_files_to_efs
    result = s3.download_file('trigger-test', key, efs_loci)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 170, in download_file
    return transfer.download_file(
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
    future.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 126, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 150, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/download.py", line 571, in _main
    fileobj.seek(offset)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/utils.py", line 367, in seek
    self._open_if_needed()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/utils.py", line 350, in _open_if_needed
    self._fileobj = self._open_function(self._filename, self._mode)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/utils.py", line 261, in open
    return open(filename, mode)
```

My hunch is that this has to do with the local mount path specified in the Lambda function versus the `Root directory path` in the Details portion of the EFS access point configuration. Ultimately, I want the `test.vcf` file I upload to S3 to be downloaded to the EFS folder: `/mnt/efs/vcfs/`.

Relevant files:

**serverless.yml:**

```
service: LambdaEFS-trigger-test
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-XXXXXXXX
      - sg-XXXXXXXX
      - sg-XXXXXXXX
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-XXXXXXXXXX


functions:
  cfnPipelineTrigger:
    handler: handler.download_files_to_efs
    description: Lambda to download S3 file to EFS folder.
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: trigger-test
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/
            - suffix: .vcf
          existing: true
    fileSystemConfig:
      localMountPath: /mnt/efs
      arn: arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXX:access-point/fsap-XXXXXXX
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:ListBucket
        Resource:
          - arn:aws:s3:::trigger-test
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:GetObjectVersion
        Resource:
          - arn:aws:s3:::trigger-test/uploads/* 
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - elasticfilesystem:ClientMount
        - elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite
        - elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess
        Resource:
        - arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXX:file-system/fs-XXXXXX

plugins:
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function

package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - '**/*'
  include:
    - handler.py
```

**handler.py**:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'us-west-2')

def download_files_to_efs(event, context):
        """
        Locates the S3 file name (i.e. S3 object "key" value) the initiated the Lambda call, then downloads the file
        into the locally attached EFS drive at the target location.
        :param: event | S3 event record
        :return: dict
        """
        print(event)

        key = event.get('Records')[0].get('s3').get('object').get('key') # bucket: trigger-test, key: uploads/test.vcf
        efs_loci = f"/mnt/efs/vcfs/{key.split('/')[-1]}" # '/mnt/efs/vcfs/test.vcf
        print("key: %s, efs_loci: %s" % (key, efs_loci))
        result = s3.download_file('trigger-test', key, efs_loci)
        if result:
            print('Download Success...')
        else:
            print('Download failed...')
        return { 'status_code': 200 }
```

**EFS Access Point details:**

- **Details**

  - `Root directory path:` /vcfs
- **POSIX**

  - `USER ID`: 1000
  - `Group ID`: 1000
- **Root directory creation permissions**

  - `Owner User ID`: 1000
  - `Owner Group ID`: 1000
  - `POSIX permissions to apply to the root directory path`: 777

Comment: Does the `vcfs` directory already exist in the EFS filesystem? You don't appear to be creating it anywhere

Comment: It does not currently exist no, but I recall reading in the AWS docs that the EFS directory creation permissions you establish in the access point would allow the directory to be made if it doesn't already exist. I also tried deploying this application after SSHing into the EC2 instance to which the EFS is mounted and manually creating the `vcfs` directory in `/mnt/efs/`, but I still get the same error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local path is `localMountPath: /mnt/efs`. So in your code you should be using only this path (not `/mnt/efs/vcfs`):

```
efs_loci = f"/mnt/efs/{key.split('/')[-1]}" # '/mnt/efs/test.vcf
```

Comment: When I SSH into the EC2 instance to which the EFS is mounted, I indeed see `/mnt/efs/vcfs/test.vcf` there with your correction. The only weird thing is the `handler.py` returns `Download failed`, so the `results` variable is empty (even though the download worked)...